# issue with hidden image on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am aware this topic has been raised severals, however i have a slight confusion with displaying an image on a MouseOver. I currently have a `div` container with a coloured background that displays when you hover it. [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/products.php) - *scroll down the image at the bottom*

The issue i am having is that i have a hidden button which i only want to display when the user hovers over `.product-shot-bg` i have made an attempt with trying to activate this function but i'm unable to get it to work..here what i've done thus far...

```
<script>
function show(#viewProductBtn){
    document.getElementById(#viewProductBtn) = "visible";
}

function hide(#viewProductBtn){
    document.getElementById(#viewProductBtn) = "Hidden";
}
 </script>

 <style>
 .product-shot-bg{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: 208px;
    height: 453px;
}

.product-shot-bg:hover{
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

    #viewProductBtn{
    background: url(css/images/viewProductBtn.png) no-repeat;
    width: 197px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    visibility: hidden;
}
     </style>

   <!-- Html -->

   <div class="product-shot-bg" onMouseOver="show('#viewProductBtn')"      onMouseOut="hide('#viewProductBtn')"> <a href="#" id="viewProductBtn "></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- You are confusing `document.getElementById` with jQuery's [ID selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). The former takes the `id` of the element, whilst the latter, uses the syntax `#id`. Thus, if you intend to use `document.getElementById`, you should pass it the `id` ***without*** the `#`;
- JavaScript identifiers/names can't start with `#` so you should remove them from your `show` and `hide` functions;
- You want to modify the `style.visibility` property to either `hidden` or `visible` in your `show/hide` functions;
- There's an extra whitespace in the `id` `"viewProductBtn "`.

Here's a fixed version of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(viewProductBtn){
    document.getElementById(viewProductBtn).style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hide(viewProductBtn) {
    document.getElementById(viewProductBtn).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>

<div class="product-shot-bg" onMouseOver="show('viewProductBtn')"      onMouseOut="hide('viewProductBtn')"><a href="#" id="viewProductBtn"></a>​
```

And a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsSbh/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with jquery:

```js
function show() {
  $("#viewProductBtn").show();
}

function hide() {
  $("#viewProductBtn").hide();
}
```

hope this helps!